# Gson library imports not exist

Tags: android, gradle, gson

I just tried to upgrade my dependencies but, the import classes are missing now. I think something broke in this upgraded version.

These are my current Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

And following classes are missing at compilation time `Gson` and `GsonBuilder`

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Hint: There are no new imports to load.

Comment: Try invalidate and restart. It will help

Comment: I have used  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

Comment: @webaddicted i did and nothing happened

Comment: @elhamdabiri i need to use latest libs

Answer (score 1):

I also see the same problem
[image: gson 2.8.6]

But it seems to be resolved in 2.8.7
[image: gson 2.8.7]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed from version 2.8.5 to 2.8.6 in regards to **com.google.code.gson:gson**.

Below is the content of the com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6 version of the jar. You can see Gson and GsonBuilder classes are present. I don't know which IDE are you using, but you should check how dependencies are resolved in your project.
You might use `gradlew dependencies` command and check the dependency tree. Be sure
com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6 is properly resolved.

Part of the result of running `gradle dependencies` command

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9
|    |         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5 -> 2.8.6
\--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6
```

This is a screenshot of dependencies resolved in IntelliJ for com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6, you can clearly see classes are present in correct package:

[image]

Comment: I'm using android studio IDEA but there is something that went wrong on my side I don't know about it and it happened in all of my projects, not just this project https://prnt.sc/13f4vg7

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to happen sometimes when upgrading the IDE, ***its a Sync Issue***

**Simple solution**:

In **build.gradle**

`implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'`   [*is the version you want, but doesn't work*]

Rollback & Sync, Rollforward & Sync

`implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'`  -->  Sync  --> `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'`   -->   Sync

Should work if your lucky :)  If not, invalidate caches, reload and roll back and forth again.